# What function executes in VBA when changing a calendar event

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, outlook-addin, appointment

I have VBA code in Outlook that adds a calendar event in a google calendar when the event is added in Outlook.  The code is also able to delete an event in a google calendar when the event is deleted from Outlook.

I have this code at the top of the VBA code:

```
Dim WithEvents curCal As Items
Dim WithEvents DeletedItems As Items
Dim newCalFolder As Outlook.Folder
```

The private sub that adds an event looks like this:

```
Private Sub curCal_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim cAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim moveCal As AppointmentItem
    ....
    Item.Save
End Sub
```

The code that deletes an event looks like this:

```
Private Sub DeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' only apply to appointments
    If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
    ' if using a category on copied items, this may speed it up.
    If Item.Categories = "moved" Then Exit Sub
    ...
End Sub
```

Both of these functions work as expected.

Now I need to code a sub that will execute when the event is modified so I can send the modifications to google.

I assume I need to create Private Sub curCal_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(ByVal Item As Object) but I dont know what the xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx would be.

Anybody know what the sub name should be where I can place code that will execute after an Outlook calendar event has been changed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) event which is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed:

```
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object) 
 Dim prompt As String 
 If VBA.Format(Item.Start, "h") >= "17" And Item.Sensitivity <> olPrivate Then 
   prompt = "Appointment occurs after hours. Mark it private?" 
   If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
     Item.Sensitivity = olPrivate 
     Item.Display 
   End If 
 End If 
End Sub
```

But there is no information what exactly has been changed, only the item changed is passed as a parameter.

For that reason you may consider handling the [AppointmentItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.propertychange) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, `Subject`) of an instance of the parent object is changed. In that case the name of the property that was changed is passed as a parameter.

Also you may find the [MailItem.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.write) event helpful. It is fired when an object is saved, either explicitly (for example, using the `Save` or `SaveAs` methods) or implicitly (for example, in response to a prompt when closing the item's inspector).

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
Private Sub myItem_Write(Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim myResult As Integer 
 myItem = "The item is about to be saved. Do you wish to overwrite the existing item?" 
 myResult = MsgBox(myItem, vbYesNo, "Save") 
 If myResult = vbNo Then 
   Cancel = True  
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Public Sub Initialize_Handler() 
 Const strCancelEvent = "Application-defined or object-defined error" 
 
 On Error GoTo ErrHandler 
 
   Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
   myItem.Save 
 Exit Sub 
 
 ErrHandler: 
   MsgBox Err.Description 
 If Err.Description = strCancelEvent Then 
   MsgBox "The event was cancelled." 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried using the ItemChange but that also fires when an event was added.  Is there a way to determine if ItemChange is firing because of the initial save of the item or truly a change in the data?

Comment: Helpful events are `PropertyChange` and `Write`. Please check out my post updated.